# Sapui5 opa5 How to upload a file using opa5 script

Tags: sapui5

im facing an issue in Uploading a file using OPA5 Script.
Can you please help me.

Please look my code..

xml::

```
<sap.ui.unified:FileUploader
                    id="fileUploader"
                    name="myFileUpload"
                    uploadUrl="upload/"
                    width="400px"
                    tooltip="Upload your file to the local server"
                    />
```

## OPA Script ::

```
When.waitFor({
                            id: "fileUploader",
                            viewName: sViewName,
                            //actions: new Press(),
                            success : function (oFirstItem) {
                                oFirstItem.$().trigger("tap");
                                Opa5.assert.ok(true, "Upload Dialog got opened");
                            },
                            errorMessage: "Form Was not Submitted"
                        });
```

Can you please help me to apply right code to upload a file using OPA script.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The uploading itself would be tested in the UI5 library somewhere already. Testing if the methods are called should suffice, no? If you're curious how SAP tests the FileUploader, I'm sure you'll find that test on GitHub.

Comment: Im not able to find any link or code in Github on OPA test scripts. Can you please share the links to me?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really want to upload a real file, you can pass parameters to the `fireChange` function.
You can use action:

```
 actions: function (oFileUploader) {
                            var mParameters = {
                                files: {
                                    "0": {
                                        "name": "something",
                                        "type": "application/gzip",
                                        "size": 123,
                                        "lastModifiedDate": "2013-08-14T09:42:09.000Z",
                                        "webkitRelativePath": ""
                                    },
                                    "length": 1
                                },
                                newValue: "\"newValueOfTheFile.tgz\" "
                            };

                            oFileUploader.fireChange(mParameters);
                        }
```

Then you can use `fireUploadComplete` function (to tell that upload is finished) in the same action, or in another (if you want to check something while "uploading" the file.