# Can't get the file path for upload file in sapui5 opa test

Tags: file-upload, sapui5, opa

I am writing OPA test for download and upload file using sapui5. However, i can't input the file in the file uploader dialog input box. as far as i know, i can use environment variable __dirname to input the file when i write sapuiveri5 tests. But in Opa, it seems impossible. Is there anyone know about this, please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

what is more, i have checked sapui5 SDK, but can't find anything to solve my problem. I check the thread below [Sapui5 opa5 How to upload a file using opa5 script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605572/sapui5-opa5-how-to-upload-a-file-using-opa5-script/50626199#50626199). But it seems little help for me.